# Socket.io Iterate over array

Tags: arrays, node.js, sockets

i have been looking for an answer to my problem for a while now, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I will try to be as detailed as possible.

When user's visit the site, each user gets their own room, using this function:

```
socket.on('join', function(id){
    socket.join(id.id);
    console.log('user: ' + id.id + ' connected');
});
```

I have a Status Table and Comments Table.

I have this ajax function which sends the comment form data to the comments controller, saves the comment and then retrieves an array of id's from the person who created the status and all people who have commented on that status, the array is [7,8,9]. I then pass this data to the Socket.io server.

```
$('.comments-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).closest('.comments-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/'+websiteName+'/comments/add',
        data: formData
    }).done(function(data){
        socket.emit('comment', {user_id: data});
    });
});
```

My problem is, is in the Socket.io server i'm trying to iterate over the id's array that was passed, and then for each id i want to send a notification. I have it working for sending a single socket a notification by passing just one id but i just can't figure out how to send multiple notifications in socket.io from an array.

I know its not how you would do it but just as an example of what i'm looking for is:

```
socket.on('comment', function(data){
    var id = data.user_id; // id's array = [7,8,9]
    for(var user_id in id)
    {
        socket.to(user_id).emit('notification');
    }
});
```

**Update**:
I have found that if i write the forEach function like this it works

```
socket.on('comment', function(data){
    [7,8,9].forEach(function (user_id) {
        console.log('Notification sent to: ' + user_id);
        socket.to(user_id).emit('notification')
    });
});
```

but it will not work with the passed in data.user_id, even though it is an array of [7,8,9]

```
socket.on('comment', function(data){
    data.user_id.forEach(function (user_id) {
        console.log('Notification sent to: ' + user_id);
        socket.to(user_id).emit('notification')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for statement will do the trick

```
for (var i = 0; i < id; i++) {
  socket.to(id[i]).emit('notification')
}
```

Or a `forEach`

```
data.user_id.forEach(function (user_id) {
  socket.to(user_id).emit('notification')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have mentioned i had already tried a for statement and tried yours again but nothing happens. I have just tried the forEach but that gives me an error [TypeError: undefined is not a function], any ideas?

Comment: On what line are you getting the `TypeError`?

Comment: I don't know to be honest i'm using this function to log the errors: socket.on('error', function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });. [TypeError: undefined is not a function] is all im getting in the command prompt

Comment: I figured out the error had something to do with console.log in the socket.on('error') function. not getting any errors now but the data.user_id.forEach is still not sending each user a notification.

Comment: This is what the debugger says: 
socket.io.js:3715 engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "pong", data "undefined" +1ms